# Serving images in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, assets

For every version of my app, I upload my assets to the cloud CDN, and the images on the website are loaded as something like `imagename-somehash`.

I have static images that are large, i.e like carousel images, which don't change often or at all. So even when the app changes, they can remain cached by clients who previously visited the website.

How would one do that? Any images I have under `app/assets` folder gets upload to CDN with the `imagename-somehash` format, so the image changes with every version of the app.

I'm using rails 4.2. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

In rails guides there is an article [What is Fingerprinting and Why Should I Care?](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) which gives some insights about that hash on the end of a file and how it works. 
Check your environments files. In production you may want `config.assets.digest` to be true.

Answer (score 0):

You can put these images in public folder and can mention full url in views for these images

OR You can also put it on

```
vendor/assets/images
```

but in that case you would have to disabled precompile path

If you want to serve only some assets from your CDN, you can use custom :host option your asset helper, which overwrites value set in config.action_controller.asset_host.

```
 <%= asset_path 'image.png', host: 'mycdnsubdomain.fictional-cdn.com' %>
```

Comment: so If I put them in that location, their location on the CDN won't be `image.png-2181281imaginary-hash` right? but rather `image.png`?